# Are the Nine Bright Shiners based on the planets?

Tags: old-kingdom

In the *Old Kingdom* series by Garth Nix, the Nine Bright Shiners are powerful Free Magic spirits, essentially gods, that shaped the world in which the story takes place (and, it is implies, a few others).

Of course, there were nine "Bright Shiners" in real life at the time the relevant books were written: the nine planets of the Solar System, before the demotion of Pluto, which of course also happen to (mostly) be named after gods. In addition, the greatest of the Bright Shiners is called Orannis, which sounds rather similar to Ouranos, primordial Greek sky god and namesake of the planet Uranus.

Is each of the Nine based on a planet? And if so, which planet corresponds to which spirit?

Comment: Umm...  Surely, since any observer is presumably located _on_ one of the planets, there would only be 8 others shining?  Note also that in real life only 5 planets (Mercury, Venus, Mars, Jupiter, Saturn) are naked-eye visible.  (And the Galilean moons of Jupiter are far more visible than Neptune, much less Pluto.)

Comment: @DavidW - Of course, but I am not sure that matters for a fantasy book. If they are based on the planets, as I suspect may be the case based on the clues in the question and some other indications in the story, the name seems likely to be *indicative* rather than astronomically accurate.

Comment: Assumedly Garth Nix named them after the line in "Green Grow the Rushes, O" - "Nine for the nine bright shiners". The meaning of the song, though, is pretty much unknown.

Answer (score 4):

The "nine bright shiners" is not a reference to the nine planets (at the time of writing).  It is actually a much older quote from the call and response (antiphon) song "[Green Grow the Rushes, O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_Grow_the_Rushes,_O)" ([catalogued](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roud_Folk_Song_Index) as a version of [Roud number](https://www.vwml.org/vwml-help-2/) [133](https://www.vwml.org/search?q=rn133&is=1)).  The song comes from the English west country and is believed to be hundreds of years old, much too old to include a reference to Pluto (and presumably Neptune as well).

The lyrics includes a number of enigmatic reference (several of them astronomical) in the lyrics.  Some of them are not really understood.  However, the "nine bright shiners" do seem to have a comparatively straightforward interpretation, most likely referring to the sun, moon, and the first seven planets, which can be seen by the naked eye and were known by 1800.  (Uranus is not among the classical planets, and it was discovered [William Herschel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Herschel) using a telescope.  However, under ideal conditions, it is just barely visible to the naked eye.)  Wikipedia has this to say about the interpretation of the ninth verse:

> "Nine for the nine bright shiners"
>
> The nine may be an astronomical reference:  the Sun, Moon and five planets known before 1781 yields seven and to this may be added the sphere of the fixed stars and the Empyrean, or it may refer to the nine orders of angels.  Sharp records no variants in Somerset, but that Sabine Baring-Gould found a Devon variant "The nine delights" which Sharp glosses as "the joys of Mary"....

I think "Green Grow the Rushes, O" is a beautiful song, strictly musically; however, the second verse is rather racist (mentioning lily-white boys), so I don't normally ever sing or listen to it myself.  [Here's a professional performance](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cjht2xQripM), for those interested.

Comment: Just to note that Uranus and Neptune are not considered naked-eye planets (Uranus is possibly barely naked-eye visible, but Neptune is definitely not).